# How to customize notice in the checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

This notification occurs when a country has no shipping methods. It can be seen in this video capture:

https://youtu.be/iemX9j3VjqQ

I am finding it extremely difficult to understand this process. I can't find documentation about it. The "woocommerce-table-rate-shipping" plugin may be involved. Any help in understanding how this notification is generated and how it can be customized is welcome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be part of the WC core, nor `woocommerce-table-rate-shipping` plugin. Possibly another plugin, or active theme. If you use some IDE (like VS Code, PhpStorm etc.) use bulk search to find that string (look in `plugins` folder, or in your parent/child theme folders).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did it, this is the strange thing. That string seems not to exist in the code.

Comment: It might also exist in the database. I would look in `wp_options` table (`option_value` column) or do a full database export and search directly in the file.